# docker containers stops a very long time

Tags: node.js, docker, ubuntu, puppeteer

when Im trying to stop docker container it take a long time, a few min, why?
I use:

```
 sudo aa-remove-unknown
 sudo docker stop $(docker ps -a -q)
 sudo docker rm $(docker ps -a -q)
 sudo docker stop $(docker ps -a -q) -f
 sudo docker rm $(docker ps -a -q) -f
```

Containers restarting every 30 min. and about 3-5 min. takes to killing.

Comment: Do you have any `Dockerfile` to see the running commands? Also run `sudo top` on your server to see if you have any high consuming process.

Comment: Your question is a little sparse.. Try expanding a bit. how long is "a long time"? What have you tried to speed things up? What behavior are you expecting.  This post helped me ask better questions (and get better answers) on SO - https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Its impossible to answer without knowing what your docker is doing. Maybe it is trying to connect to an endpoint without success, in that case, until timeout is reached it wont stop. But there are like a million different scenarios that can result in a slow stop. So check what the docker is actually doing first, and fix the issue based on that

Answer (score 1):

`docker stop` sends a `SIGTERM` signal to the container, which will allow your processes to gracefully stop, this can often take time.

There's an excellent [blog post](https://blog.repl.it/killing-containers-at-scale) from repl.it that dives deep into this topic.